# Send file and information about attack from honeypot to central repository trough HTTP

Tags: security, http, submission, malware, honeypot

Hello people someone knows Dionaea honeypot?

I'm trying to send binary information collected locally and attack collected locally on the honeypot to a central server and I can not get it.

I've tried using HTTP Post, Python CGI, and I can not get it.
The honeypot has a service that lets you send data via HTTP (submit_http.py: http://src.carnivore.it/dionaea/commit/?id=cfd2be8cf7484c781384648cf1c9223afc2bd3c1) and I have a PHP file on the central server which was originally developed for nepenthes (submit.php: http://www.remoteroot.net/2008/07/21/nepenthes-submit-http-server-with-file-upload/) and wanted to receive the files as well as information about each attack associated parameters through HTTP POST.
Why does the submit.php is not working?!

I have my dionaea.conf like this:

```
submit_http = {
                        url = "http://central_machine_IP/submit.php"
                        email = "zzzzzzzz@yyyyy.com"
                        user = "uuuuuuu"
                        pass = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                }
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: From the submitting machine, can you actually hit the central machine? Try hitting it with a command line operation like curl and make sure that works.

Comment: He finds the central machine I tested with your browser.
In dionaea Log appears to me the following error:

Comment: *my browser, I'm sorry but im not english.

Answer (score 0):

dionaea log error:

```
[10022011 17:51:14] curl module.c:202: DOWNLOAD DONE:
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yyy => (0)
[10022011 17:51:14] logsql dionaea/logsql.py:601: complete for attackid 5241
[10022011 17:51:14] test dionaea/test.py:51: your configuration lacks urls
to submit to defaults
[10022011 17:51:14] python module.c:959: NameError at NameError("global name
'submithttp_report' is not defined",)
[10022011 17:51:14] python module.c:984:
/opt/dionaea/lib/dionaea/python/dionaea/submit_http.py:56 in
handle_incident_dionaea_download_complete_unique
[10022011 17:51:14] python module.c:985:      mr =
submithttp_report(i.sha512, i.md5, icd.file)
[10022011 17:51:14] python module.c:984: binding.pyx:975 in
dionaea.core.c_python_ihandler_cb (binding.c:8605)
[10022011 17:51:14] python module.c:985:      None
```

I hid the original ip by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: With curl the honeypot downloads the worm from the web and then had to send it to my central server with the submit_http.py module and it seems that this is causing problems.